Why can't I open a Mac file (operation not permitted) until AFTER one sudo command?
Here's a mystery. First, I can't open a specific file on my Mac, even though I have read permission:
$ cd Downloads
$ ls -l "WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4"
-rw-r--r--@ 1 smith staff  16807637 May  2 15:19 WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4

$ file "WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4"
WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4: cannot open: Operation not permitted

I can read it with sudo...
$ sudo file "WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4"
Password:
WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4: ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]

...but then comes the strange part. After executing the previous command, the file remains readable by me without sudo:
$ file "WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4"
WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4: ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]

The file remains readable by me for some time afterward, even after I log out and log back in. Sometime in the next 24 hours, however, it becomes unreadable again. What's going on here?
I noticed this problem because my system backup (with rsync) complained about "operation not permitted."
In case it helps, here is the output of xattr, but the attributes (once they can be displayed) look the same as many other files in the same folder that are perfectly readable.
$ xattr -l "WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4"
xattr: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4'
$ sudo xattr -l "WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4"
com.apple.macl: 
com.apple.provenance: 
com.apple.quarantine: 0087;6633e72d;WhatsApp;
$ xattr -l "WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4"
com.apple.macl: 
com.apple.provenance: 
com.apple.quarantine: 0087;6633e72d;WhatsApp;


Is xattr output exactly the same before and after sudo ?

xattr can't open the file before sudo ("operation not permitted"), but the output with & without sudo is identical. I have updated the question with more xattr output.

One explanation is that sudo xattr -l ... updated extended attributes, that's why xattr -l works after that.

Thanks, but that can't be the reason, because sudo file also makes the file accessible, but the file command and doesn't update anything. (Also xattr -l is a read operation, not a write, according to the man page.)

You cannot rule out the possibility that any read operation run by root updates extended attributes.

Thanks. Even if that's true, the file reverts to being unreadable by regular users within 24 hours or so. I don't see how that would happen to just this one file on the entire filesystem....

can you do sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine "WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4", sudo xattr -d com.apple.macl "WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4" and sudo xattr -d com.apple.provenance "WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4" ?

Thanks. I ran your commands. I'm still getting "Operation not permitted" errors from reading the file 24 hours later.

Try to run following two commands to see if they give any clues :
sudo fs_usage | grep "WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4"
# Leave this running for 24 hours

log show | grep "WhatsApp Video 2024-05-02 at 15.06.16.mp4"


I never did figure out the problem, but I did eliminate the symptom. I copied the video file and deleted the original. No more errors.
